# How can I tell if an Azure client secret is being used?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm maintaining a few apps that are registered with Azure AD that have client secrets that are expiring soon. Is there a good way to know whether the secrets are in use?

Comment: Change them and listen for the screams? ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Haha! That may be what I end up doing. :-)

Comment: @HongOoi oh I came here to suggest the same :D

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how useful this is going to be for you but I derived the applications/users that are using the app by looking under the Enterprise Application sign-in logs. Since these represent instances of your application being used, I believe this could help you identify whether it has been used recently.

I've not personally done it at scale but only once when I had to figure out where my app was being used (it was a messy environment). You could first try to validate it with any app for which you do not see activity, together with any documentation/knowledge you have on hand.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the secret usage in the sign-in logs.  (Entra ID > Sign-in Logs > Service Principle Sign-ins tab.)  Drill into the log and you will see "Credential key ID" being used.

You can also query the key ID in log analytics.

AADServicePrincipalSignInLogs
| where ServicePrincipalCredentialKeyId == "secret id"
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(30d)